# Ocr with Google vision api on characters inside a box

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I tried using google vision api to extract text from a form but it couldn't recognize characters in a box. How can I achieve ocr with google vision api on the attached form?  [my_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdpjU.jpg)